# Rails: validating a field is present only if another is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

I have a model where there are two fields that can technically be null. The field names are `:is_activated` and `:activated_at`. `:activated_at` is only required if `:is_activated` is set to `true`. It does not need to be present if `:is_activated` is `false`. What's the appropriate way in Rails to set this validation directly into ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use a [Proc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Proc.html) on the `:activated_at` validator.

```
validates :activated_at, :presence, if: Proc.new { |a| a.is_activated? }
```

---

Recommended Reading:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-proc-with-if-and-unless
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html

---

*Finally, you should consider renaming `:is_activated` to simply `:activated`. This is considered better practice in Rails. The `is_` prefix is used in other languages for boolean attributes because their method names don't support a `?` character. Ruby does, and Rails generates `___?` methods on boolean attributes. Because of this it's better to just call the attribute `:activated` and check it with `activated?`.*

Answer (score 7):

#### Non-Boolean Attributes.

If you're not using a `Boolean` attribute, like `is_activated`, and want to ensure that one attribute is present when another, non-Boolean attribute is present, you can simplify it:

```
validates :activated_at, presence: true, if: :activated_by?
```

`activated_by?` will return `false` when `null` and `true` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
validates :activated_at, presence: true, if: :is_activated?

def is_activated?
  self.is_activated
end
```

This will only validate `:activated_at` if the method `is_activated?` returns `true`.