# Validate the Value of One Attrribute Based on Another Attribute's Value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

How do you enforce presence of another attribute if a given attribute is present?

I have a user model with country and state attributes. I want to validate when the user tries to sign up, that he didn't bypass client side validation and submit a malicious request with `params[:country]="canada"` and `params[:state]="new_york"`.

Comment: Didn't get you.. Please clarify.

Comment: If I am not wrong you want to validate if user is from canada, he should not be able to select new york as his state,correct?

Comment: @sontya selection is client side, that validation is done, and I would rather not use a gem

Comment: @propster - by selection I mean to say saving it to database, my bad. So somewhere you have write which countries should allow which states right.

Comment: Take a look at the following SO question if you're looking for validating the presence of an attribute if another attribute is also present: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13750436/293280

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example implementation :

```
validates :state, inclusion: { in: [ON, BC, AB],
    message: "%{state} is not valid" }, if: :country_is_canada?

def country_is_canada?
  country == 'Canada'
end
```

Comment: spot on. i think u have a typo tho @railsouter after valid

Comment: Thanks, corrected. That's what happens when you answer questions so fast lol